# How to get sha256 hash output as binary data instead of hex using powershell?

Tags: powershell, base64, sha256, payload

Is there an in-built method to generate SHA256 as a binary data for a given string ? Basically, I am using below bash script to first generate a hash as a binary data and then do a base64 encoding. All I want to have is the exact thing in Powershell so that both the outputs are identical:

```
clearString="test"
payloadDigest=`echo -n "$clearString" | openssl dgst -binary -sha256 | openssl base64 `
echo ${payloadDigest}
```

In powershell, I can get the SHA256 in hex using the below script, but then struggling to get it as a binary data:

```
$ClearString= "test"
$hasher = [System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm]::Create('sha256')
$hash = $hasher.ComputeHash([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($ClearString))

$hashString = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($hash)
$256String= $hashString.Replace('-', '').ToLower()
$sha256String="(stdin)= "+$256String
$sha256String
```

I can then use [Convert]::ToBase64String($Bytes) to convert to base64 but in between how do I get a binary data similar to bash output before I pass it to base64 conversion.

Comment: `$hasher.ComputeHash()` returns a `Byte[]` array, so you can just do `[Convert]::ToBase64String($hash)` if I'm not mistaken. By doing `[System.BitConverter]::ToString($hash)` you are converting the binary data into a hex string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are over-doing this, since the [ComputeHash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.computehash?view=netframework-4.8) method already returns a `Byte[]` array (binary data). To do what (I think) you are trying to achieve, don't convert the bytes to string, because that will result in a hexadecimal string.

```
$ClearString= "test"
$hasher = [System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm]::Create('sha256')
$hash = $hasher.ComputeHash([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($ClearString))
# $hash is a Byte[] array

# convert to Base64
[Convert]::ToBase64String($hash)
```

returns

> n4bQgYhMfWWaL+qgxVrQFaO/TxsrC4Is0V1sFbDwCgg=

Comment: Thanks Theo, this was very helpful. I see where I went wrong now.